# Escape quote in Dart Regex

Tags: dart

I'm trying to use the regex `/^[a-zA-Z0-9_$&+:;=?@#|'<>.^*()%!-]+$/` with dart regex. I've seen you can use raw strings. So Ive put the above in between `r''` like this:

`r'^[a-zA-Z0-9_$&+:;=?@#|'<>.^*()%!-]+$'` but  the `'` is messing it up. How do I tell dart this is a special character..

**EDIT**

I tried this but it doesn't seem to work

```
static final RegExp _usernameRegExp = RegExp(
    r"^[a-zA-Z0-9_$&+:;=?@#|'<>.^*()%!-]+$",
  );
```

So I have a TextField with a text controller for a username. A method like this

```
static bool isValidUsername(String username) {
    return (_usernameRegExp.hasMatch(username));  
  }
```

I pass the controller.text as the username.
I've a function:

```
bool get isUserNameValid => (Validators.isValidUsername(userNameTextController.text.trim()));
```

I can type all the given characters in to the textbook but not `'`

Comment: Since your regex does not contain `"`, you could just do: `r"^[a-zA-Z0-9_$&+:;=?@#|'<>.^*()%!-]+$"`

Comment: thanks @julemand101 I did try that but it doesn't seem to work. I've edited the question to show what exactly I've done..

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"? As far as I can see, the RegExp is handled correctly but maybe there are some characters you need to escape since they have a meaning in RegExp. E.g. the `()` should properly be `\(\)` since parenthesis have a meaning in RegExp. But this escaping is part of writing a RegExp and not especially to Dart. Use a service like this to create your RegExp before using it in Dart: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Also, could you provide some testcases which we can use to verify that a suggested solution does what you want? Just example on input and expected output.

Comment: Are you sure about it is the `'` char there gives your problems? If I do: `print(isValidUsername("test'"));` it returns `true` using your current RegExp example.

Comment: apologies for not getting back..

Comment: Ok, but could you answer my questions instead of making an apology? :)

Comment: I will, It does still give a problem. I'll put it in a dartpad with a textfield ..to show you what I mean.

Answer (score 4):

Your RegExp source contains `'`, so you can't use that as string delimiter without allowing escapes. It also contains `$` so you want to avoid allowing escapes.

You can use `"` as delimiter instead, so a raw string like `r"..."`.

However, Dart also has "multi-line strings" which are delimited by `"""` or `'''`. They can, but do not have to, contain newlines. You can use those for strings containing both `'` and `"`. That allows `r'''...'''`.

And you can obviously also use escapes for all characters that mean something in a string literal.

So, for your code, that would be one of:

```dart
r'''^[\w&+:;=?@#|'<>.^*()%!-]+$'''
r"^[\w&+:;=?@#|'<>.^*()%!-]+$"
'^[\\w&+:;=?@#|\'<>.^*()%!-]+\$'
```

(I changed `A-Za-z0-9$_` to `\w`, because that's precisely what `\w` means).

In practice, I'll always use a raw string for regexps. It's far too easy, and far too dangerous, to forget to escape a backslash, so use one of the first two options.

I'd probably escape the `-` too, making it `[....\-]` instead of relying on the position to make it non-significant in the character class. It's a fragile design that breaks if yo add one more character at the end of the character class, instead of adding it before the `-`. It's less fragile if you escape the `-`.